# Preventing Windows 7 from hiding file size

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Here's something that really annoys me about Windows 7.

When Windows 7 detects that a folder contains just music files, it changes the categories that show on the details view. From Name, Date Modified, Type and Size it changes to more music-relevant ones like Name, Track Number, Title, Artists, etc.

This is really annoying. I appreciate Windows trying to help me, but I'm much more interested in the data that was previously displayed and now isn't, like Size and Date Modified, than the Track Number or Artists.

How can I make Windows show me Size, etc? In case this is not obvious, I *don't* want a solution only for this specific case; I want a solution for every situation in which Windows suddenly decides to change the categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the folder's type (and that of all sub-folders too if required):

[image: 1]

Specifying **General Items** for a top-level folder and propagating it to all sub-folders should fix everything in one go.

You can also [set a default folder template for all folders](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/15699-folder-template-default.html) if you want via the registry.

There's also an app called [ExplorerView](http://www.sdsoftware.org/software/explorerview/) that claims to "give you the ability to turn off the way Explorer attempts to auto-detect the contents of a folder":

[image: 2]